# Fresh php5-fpm installation unable to start

Tags: php

Upon executing the commands:

```
root@localhost:/# start php5-fpm
php5-fpm start/running, process 21234
root@localhost:/# status php5-fpm
php5-fpm stop/waiting
root@localhost:/# tail /var/log/php5-fpm.log
[...] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[...] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[...] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[...] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[...] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

When i start php5-fpm, it looks ok.  I check the status, and it is stopped.  I check the error log, and the only thing that appears, is the result of php5-fpm testing the .conf file.  It shows no errors..

My `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` conf is as follows:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
log_level = error

include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

I have one conf file within `pool.d`, and I removed the file to make sure that wasn't the culprit.  still to no avail.

Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: could you change the error_level to debug and restart again? this time, it should give you a lot more info in your logs.

Comment: same thing @khuderm . it's like it doesn't even apply correctly.  in my `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` file, it does show `DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"` so i know it's using the correct one.  it's like it doesn't even update the log level at all..

Comment: you sir, deserve the bounty.  doing that, actually *did* spit out the error that i was facing and i was able to figure out my issue.  go ahead and give an answer, and i'll give you some rep.

Comment: I made the comment and removed the comment. glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`# php5-fpm -y /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` try running that. It will start it in foreground and may give you additional data